# How to generate objective-c classes from sqlite file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, orm

I have this little issue with creating my objective-c models from an `sqlite database` file, I have already tried Vertabelo but it's limited to 100 tables in the free account (I do have more tables 147), and it seems like 'Objective-C Query Builder' ORM is not working anymore.

Does anyone have any solution or proposition, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how you can wrap sql to Objective-C **Objects**.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/misato/SQLiteManager4iOS) solution. Useful for me.

> SQLiteManager is a simple Class "wrapper" to use SQLite3 within iOS
>   SDK. It provides methods to:
>
> - connect/create a database in your documents app folder
> - do a simple query
> - **get rows in NSDictionary format**
> - close the connection
> - dump your data in sql dump format

After that use NSDictionaries to create the **models/classes** you want to achieve.

Comment: In fact i use FMDB as a wrapper it works great for me, but the thing is in generating the objectif-c class models, finally i used the free version of the Vertabelo and i used the FMDB to connect and write my DAO classes, but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: ok, you're welcome. understood.
just, NSDictionary is good and flexible enough to create any model.